# How to do Rename and Delete operations in audio file which is in SDcard

Tags: android

Here i am trying to displaying all 3Gp files in a list view then want to perform Rename and Delete operations in list items so chooses context menu to fix this here i am able to perform operations on list but those are not effecting to audio file in SDcard,suggest me hoe to do this.
here is my code to perform operations

```
    // Use the current directory as title
    path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);

    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (file.contains(".3gp")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
    // Put the data into the list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(myList);
}

final int CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE = 1;
final int CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME = 2;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME, Menu.NONE, "Rename");

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Long id = myList.getAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
    final int number_of_item_in_listview = Integer.valueOf(id.intValue());
    final int context_menu_number = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) { // retrieves the id of the item clicked. In
                                // this case it can 1,2 or 3 as we declared
                                // it earlier.
    case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "You selected item " + context_menu_number
                        + " from the context menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "You removed item " + number_of_item_in_listview
                        + " from the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        values.remove(number_of_item_in_listview);
        // myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //if this does not work,
        // reinitialize the adapter:
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                values);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        File f = new File(path + filename);
        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
            // delete it
            f.delete();
        }
        return (true);

    case CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME:

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Rename item");
        alert.setMessage("Enter new name for selected item");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        File f = new File(path + filename);
                        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
                            // delete it
                            f.delete();
                        }
                        values.set(number_of_item_in_listview, value
                                + ".3gp");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
        return (true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt");
File to = new File(sdcard,"to.txt");
from.renameTo(to);
```

and may be below link will help u:

http://androidadvices.com/how-to-rename-files-in-android-phone/

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine:Put this code where you want change the name.

```
 File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample");
            String fromFullPath = "/username556596268.mp3";
            String toFullPath = "/username.mp3";

            File from = new File(sdcard,fromFullPath);
          File to = new File(sdcard,toFullPath);
            from.renameTo(to);
from.delete();
```

here "sample" is my sdcard main directory name,"fromFullPath" is my filename it is in inside the sample directory,
"toFullPath" is my changed name.